# generate a random number between 1 and 10 in c

Tags: c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    int randomnumber;
    randomnumber = rand() % 10;
    printf("%d\n", randomnumber);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple program where randomnumber is an uninitialized int variable that is meant to be printed as a random number between 1 and 10. However, it always prints the same number whenever I run over and over again. Can somebody please help and tell me why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Read about [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand).

Comment: You most likely have bias in that selection.

Comment: @chris: Yes but the bias in this case is fairly minor; since `RAND_MAX` is at least 32767, the bias is less than one part in 3000, and if you need better quality pseudo-random numbers than that you should probably use something better than `rand()`. Still, it's probably worth addressing, especially if you want a bigger range (close to `RAND_MAX`). Question 13.16 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) shows how to do this.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Exactly, better to start right than start with problems and have to learn about and fix them later.

Comment: your_lucky_number = (rand() % 10) + 1; And, of course e.g: int min=12; int max=33; your_number = (rand() % (max+1-min)) + min;

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a different seed at every execution.

You can start to call at the beginning of your program:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Note that `% 10` yields a result from `0` to `9` and not from `1` to `10`: just add `1` to your `%` expression to get `1` to  `10`.

Comment: thanks but when i add srand(time(NULL)); right after i declare the variable randomnumber, the compiler gives me the error implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'

Comment: @Nisarg; Use `srand((unsigned)time(NULL))`. `srand()` takes an `unsigned` value as an argument.

Comment: @Nisarg you can safely ignore this message or cast the function argument to `unsigned int` to silent it.

Comment: @Nisarg; And also include `time.h` header for `time()` function.

Comment: Reseeding before every call doesn't give random numbers, it gives a hash function of the time, or whatever you used to seed. That may be good enough for some uses, but it's not using the PRNG algorithm at all.  @Nisarg, just because something appears to work, that doesn't make it right.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL))` returns nothing(void), it just sets `seed` for random number generator to current time, use `rand` (this returns int) for your random number, after call to srand (each time).

Comment: randomnumber = rand() % 11;
I thought that this code will generate numbers from 0-10, so how do I get 1-10?

Answer (score 8):

```
srand(time(NULL));

int nRandonNumber = rand()%((nMax+1)-nMin) + nMin;
printf("%d\n",nRandonNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a ready to run source code for random number generator using c taken from this site:
http://www.random-number.com/random-number-c/
. The implementation here is more general (a function that gets 3 parameters: min,max and number of random numbers to generate)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// the random function
void RandomNumberGenerator(const int nMin, const int nMax, const int  nNumOfNumsToGenerate)
{
  int nRandonNumber = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nNumOfNumsToGenerate; i++)
  {
    nRandonNumber = rand()%(nMax-nMin) + nMin;
    printf("%d ", nRandonNumber);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  RandomNumberGenerator(1,70,5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant function in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random_number(int min, int max) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    return (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: If you call this in a loop, all returned values are the same. You'd need to call `srand` somewhere else (e.g. `main`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to seed the random number generator, from `man 3 rand`

> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with  a value of 1.

and

> The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a new sequence of  pseudo-random  integers  to  be  returned  by rand(). These sequences are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value.

e.g.

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating a single random number in a program is problematic. Random number generators are only "random" in the sense that repeated invocations produce numbers from a given probability distribution.

Seeding the RNG won't help, especially if you just seed it from a low-resolution timer. You'll just get numbers that are a hash function of the time, and if you call the program often, they may not change often. You might improve a little bit by using `srand(time(NULL) + getpid())` (`_getpid()` on Windows), but that still won't be random.

The ONLY way to get numbers that are random *across* multiple invocations of a program is to get them from outside the program. That means using a system service such as `/dev/random` (Linux) or `CryptGenRandom()` (Windows), or from a service like `random.org`.

Comment: thanks lee do your know how to use a system service to get a legit random number generator on a MAC?                                                 FYI: I'm using Xcode.

Comment: I'm not a Mac guy, but I believe they are Unix-like enough that they have a `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: This depends on the usage. Do you want to write a program that encrypts sensible data? Then using RNGs naively is _very_ bad. Do you want to initialize a particle simulation? srand() and rand() should be just fine (unless you want to analyze the system in an academic setting ofcourse)